# Best DB architecture approach to store transaction and boundbook records

Tags: postgresql, database-design

This DB design is related to developing an application for a Gunshop that keeps acquisition and disposition records of firearms they bought and sold. As a database, we are using postgreSQL.

For each acquisition and disposition of a firearm to this shop there should be a transaction recorded in the database. Mainly, transaction should contain the following attributes.

```
Transaction {
        Int id
        Int gunId
        String contactId // Contact is the other party that we bought or sold the firearm
        Date date
        ENUM transactionType
        Date createdAt
        Int createdUserId
    }
```

The boundbook is a table that get derived from 2 transactions ( a gun acquisition transaction and another disposition transaction of same gun. Basically when a shop acquire a gun there should be a partial boundbook record and after disposition that same record need to be updated including

- two contacts (seller and buyer) that says from whom I bought and to whom I sold,
- Dates of acquisition and disposition
- firearm information

So I need to find a better way to store relationship between two tables.

**Approach 1:**
Store both acquisition and disposition transaction ids in boundbook record

**Approach 2:**
Store boundbook id in transaction record.
But transaction record get created first and the boundbook record get created after the transaction record. So if I use this approach then I need to update the transaction table record after I created the boundbook record

Other than that since boundbook records are derived from transaction data seems that table depend on transaction table as well.

Can you give me some insight in this? Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer aproach 1, beacuse you say boundbook is always contain acquisition and deposition information. So, no column left null or empty.